# Is there a way to run PsExec specifying a user name and password (-u -p) when running as Local System?

Tags: windows-server-2003, pstools, local-system

I have a Windows Service running as Local System on Windows Server 2003 and I'm trying to use PsExec to run a command as another user (using the `-u -p` parameters) but I keep getting `Access is denied. PsExec could not start` errors.

The following can be performed to replicate the issue:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\me>PsExec.exe -s cmd

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.

C:\WINNT\system32>whoami
nt authority\system

C:\WINNT\system32>PsExec.exe -u DOMAIN\my-user -p mypass cmd

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Access is denied.
PsExec could not start cmd:
```

In the example above, the first PsExec command (`PsExec.exe -s cmd`) will give you a command line as Local System. Then the second PsExec command (`PsExec.exe -u DOMAIN\my-user -p mypass cmd`) throws the error that I'm trying to resolve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your user account an admin account?

Comment: Do you know for certain that you can successfully start an instance of PSEXEC *inside* another instance, regardless of the user account involved? Why are you trying to run one inside the other in the first place?

Comment: @Rex Yes, the account that I'm passing via the `-u` parameter (DOMAIN\my-user in example above) is in the local Administrators group on the server.

Comment: @Twisty Yes, an instance of PsExec can be started from another instance of PsExec. For example, the command `PsExec.exe -s -i cmd` can be executed and then in the new window the command `PsExec.exe -s cmd` can be executed.

Comment: @Twisty The example of running an instance of PsExec from another instance of PsExec is only to replicate the actual issue I am having with the Windows Service running as Local System trying to use PsExec (with the `-u -p` parameters).

Comment: 1) Can you successfully execute the `PsExec.exe \\ComputerName -u DOMAIN\my-user -p mypass cmd` from *another* machine against your server? 2) What happens if you run your two `psexec` commands, but use the Local Administrator account instead of the Domain user when running the second command?

Comment: @Twisty You are definitely on to something... I just checked and I can successfully execute `PsExec.exe \\ComputerName -u DOMAIN\my-user -p mypass cmd /c hostname` from _another_ server. If I run the same command from my server using `\\ComptuerName` it continues to fail. **But, if I run the same command on my server using my server's CNAME or IP Address instead of ComputerName then it works!** Please post your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After starting your first instance of `PSEXEC.EXE` as the LocalSystem account, include the local computer's IP address in the command to start your second PSEXEC instance, like this:

```
PSEXEC.EXE \\LocalComputerIPAddress -u DOMAIN\my-user -p mypass CMD
```

---

### Explanation

The behavior you're experiencing is due to a new security feature added by Windows Server 2003's Service Pack 1 called [Loopback Check Functionality](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/926642/EN-US).  According to the linked MSKB article:

> After you [install Service Pack 1], you experience authentication issues when you try
>   to access a server locally by using its fully qualified domain name
>   (FQDN) or its CNAME alias in the following Universal Naming Convention
>   (UNC) path:
>
> ```
>     \\servername\sharename
> ```
>
> In this scenario, you experience one of the following symptoms:
>
> - You receive repeated logon windows.
> - You receive an "Access denied" error message.
> - You receive a "No network provider accepted the given network path" error message.
> - Event ID 537 is logged in the Security event log.

The article suggests two solutions (in addition to the workaround I provided above), both which involve editing the Registry to either: 1) Add host names that can be referenced in an NTLM authentication request, or 2) Disable the authentication loopback check, effectively returning the server to the pre-SP1 behavior.

According to this WindowsITPro.com article on [how PSEXEC works](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec):

> PsExec starts an executable on a remote system and controls the input and output streams of the executable's process so that you can interact with the executable from the local system. **PsExec does so by extracting from its executable image an embedded Windows service named Psexesvc and copying it to the Admin$ share of the remote system.**

So even though you're running PSEXEC against your local machine, it's using the `ADMIN$` share nonetheless, hence the reason you're running into the Loopback Check Functionality behavior change described above.

Comment: You're the hero.